# How to prevent memory leakage in wxPython subclass?

Tags: python, memory-leaks, wxpython, weak-references

I'm running Python 2.7, wxPython 2.8.12.1 and Windows 7.

I am working on a program that passes large data objects to wx.Frame and creates interactive plots.  The goal is to iterate through many data objects, creating new windows and plots for each data object.

The problem that I have run into is that with each new instance of my wx.Frame subclass, the memory usage increases dramatically.

The code below recreates my problem.

The first loop creates 10 objects, each containing an array of decreasing size. As this loop runs, the memory usage (according to Windows Task Manager) drops with each iteration.

The second loop creates 10 wx.Frame objects that hold the same arrays.  However, now the memory usage steadily increases up to 1 GB.

```
import numpy as np
import time
import wx


class MyClass():

    def __init__(self, i):
        self.x = np.arange(0, i*5000000)


#While this loop runs, memory usage decreases
for i in [10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]:
    print(i)
    m = MyClass(i)
    time.sleep(2)


class wxWindow(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self,i = None):
        super(wxWindow,self).__init__(None)
        self.x = np.arange(0, i*5000000)


#While this loop runs, memory usage increases
#until the program crashes.
for i in [10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]:
    print(i)
    app = wx.App()
    app.frame = wxWindow(i)
    app.frame.Show(True)
    app.MainLoop()
    app.Destroy()
```

I can stop the memory leakage by 2 methods:

1) By making the variable "x" local (i.e. dropping the "self."):

```
x = np.arange(0, i*5000000)
```

2) Using a weak reference:

```
self.x = weakref.ref(np.arange(0, i*5000000))
```

I can't use method #1 because I need the large data objects to be available for the whole class.  I don't know much at all about weakref objects, but so far I haven't had any luck using weak references to my data object (always get a "weakref object has no attributes" error).

Answer (score 1):

Change the last part of your code to this:

```
app = wx.App()
for i in [10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]:
    print(i)
    frame = wxWindow(i)
    frame.Show(True)
    app.MainLoop()
```

wx.App operates as a singleton (read [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/wxpython-users/7Yy5O2l_Ngs)), so you only need 1 wx.App instance per process.  You were making 10 of them. Anyway, this will cure your memory problems.

Comment: Perfect!  I've been struggling to solve this issue for a couple weeks now.  Thanks.

Comment: Let me complement you on the way you asked the question. Including code that actually runs to explain the issue makes it much easier to understand, and to come up with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you could make `x` a class attribute

```
class wxWindow(wx.Frame):
    x = np.arange(0, i*5000000)
    def __init__(self, i=None):
        super(wxWindow, self).__init__(None)
```

another way would be to explicitly `del` `x`

```
del app.frame.x
```

finally there;s probably a method of wxWindow that can handle the cleanup. eg

```
class wxWindow(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self,i=None):
        super(wxWindow, self).__init__(None)
        self.x = np.arange(0, i*5000000)

    def close(self):  # you'll have to find the correct name in the docs
        del self.x
        super(wxWindow, self).close()
```